# Restore Samsung SSD to factor default settings

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, samsung-ssd

I just installed a workstation specific windows 7 64 on Samsung evo 870 ssd drive. The windows made 3 partitions. I need to make a clean install of a consumer windows 10 over this drive - I wonder how do I restore the ssd drive to the factor settings? Maybe there is a programme for this?
Dave

Comment: Samsung EVO 870 should support the secure erase command which deletes everything in a second. Samsung Magician software allows to create a bootable USB stick to perform the reset. Other tools can also execute the secure erase command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows 10 Install USB to both delete existing partitions and then make the new partitions for Windows 10 (minimum of 3 partitions). This should work fine for you.

Please see this article (nicely complete):

[Delete partitions during Windows 10 Install](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/clean-install-Windows-10/#:%7E:text=To%20ensure%20a%20100%25%20clean,available%20space%20for%20the%20partition.)

Start with the Windows 10 ISO and after you have accepted the license agreement, you need to select "custom install"

> To perform a clean install, you’ll need to select the “Custom: Install
> Windows only” option. As the installer says — you should have a backup
> of your files and programs in order to copy them to the new
> installation after it’s complete

Then you get to the spot where you delete partitions and do a completely fresh install.

> This next part may be a bit tricky if you have multiple hard drives or
> partitions. You’ll need to delete the primary partition and the system
> partition. To ensure a 100% clean install it’s better to fully delete
> these instead of just formatting them